# search and replace crontab entry

Tags: search, replace, cron

I have a following line in the file

```
*/10 * * * * root /usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1
```

and `*/10` needs to be replaced with `*` preferably using `sed`

any inputs is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

A `sed` command line for such a replacement would be

```
sed -e 's/\*\/10\b/*/'
```